# Average while retaining singletons

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
     Gene        Sample1          Sample2         Sample3      ........
       a            1                5               7         ........     
       a            2                2               1         ........          
       a            8                5               0         ........      
       b           18               22               7         ........                
       c           76                2              27         ........   
       c           70               26              12         ........  
      ....       ......           ......          ........
```

Is there a way to take the median/mean of the repeated Gene names while retaining the not repeated ones?

Desired output:

```
     Gene        Sample1          Sample2         Sample3      ........
       a            2                5               1         ........     
       b           18               22               7         ........                
       c           73               14              19.5       ........
```

For the "a" for example I considered the median while for "c" the mean. It is possible to consider the mean only, because I have many repeats. My point is not to average when there is a gene name in single. How it is possible to easily distinguish the two cases?

Comment: I think you just need to apply mean/median per group on all columns.

Comment: If there is a single value, the average would be that value i.e. `df1 %>% group_by(Gene) %>% summarise_at(vars(starts_with('Sample')), mean)`

Comment: It seems like OP is only after the median - so `summarise_all` with `median` would likely work (with grouping beforehand)